# `Unfold` operator unsupported when exporting to ONNX

Tags: pytorch, onnx

When running

```py
torch.onnx.export(
    model,
    (im, im),
    'wow.onnx',
    verbose=True,
    opset_version=opset,
    input_names=['t0', 't1'],
    output_names=['output']
)
```

on my model. I get:

```bash
Unsupported: ONNX export of operator Unfold , input size not accessible. Please feel free to request support or submit a pull request on PyTorch GitHub.
```

Any idea which operation `Unfold` (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Unfold.html) could be replaced by so that the export succeeds?